# PHP PDO query error on table has json data type (MySQL 5.7.8-rc)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, types, mysql-json

I'm trying new json datatype on mysql 5.7. When I use native php mysql query, it works fine, but when I use PDO to query data, it shows this error:

> Error: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2036 ' in /some_folder/pdo.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /some_folder/pdo.php(12): PDO->query('select * from table_has_json_datatype') #1 {main}

Do you guys know how to solve this problem ?

Thanks.

Update with my simple test code:

```
<?php

try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=some.host;dbname=somedb;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pwd');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch(PDOException  $e){
    echo "Error1: ".$e;
}

try{
    $query = $db->query("select * from table_with_json_type");

}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error2: ".$e;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you edit your post with the code

Comment: `Error: 2036 (CR_UNSUPPORTED_PARAM_TYPE) ` - so the actual code is most likely irrelevant.

Comment: `a)` What does `echo 'CLIENT_VERSION: "', $pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION),'"';` print? (where $pdo is your acual pdo instance created be `new PDO...`) `b)` Which version of PHP do you run on exactly what OS (e.g. PHP 5.4.7/Ubuntu 11.04)

Comment: see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70384 and https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/e07e4f4bb3dca81010e4ae956dfd7de5376fdb8c

Comment: @VolkerK my PDO-mysql client version is 5.7.5-m15 and Ubuntu 14.04 with php 5.6.14, mysql 5.7.8-rc

Answer (score 14):

It's a Bug reported to PHP Developers [#70384](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70384)

The developer andrey@php.net just posted:

> The fix for this bug has been committed.
>
> Snapshots of the sources are packaged every three hours; this change
>   will be in the next snapshot. You can grab the snapshot at
>   http://snaps.php.net/.
>
> For Windows:
>
> http://windows.php.net/snapshots/   Thank you for the report, and for
>   helping us make PHP better.
>
> Fixed in PHP-5.6.19, PHP-7.0 and master (PHP-7.1)
>
> Thank You for your report

So, the JSON data type will be supported on PHP 5.6.19+
For other version there is a workaround available above.

This workaround modify the JSON field with CAST feature to a CHAR, which is fine from PHP's perspective:
Eg.:

```
select *, CAST(json_col as CHAR) as json_col from table_with_json_type
```

It's worked to me in all cases.

To Full compatibility you must use PHP-5.6.19+

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know when will the next version release ?

Comment: Casting worked for me, but the issue doesn't seem to be resolved in PHP 5.6.19

Comment: Tested on PHP 5.6.20 and it's no need use this workaround to make works.
The json data comes as jsonstring.

Would be nice have some config to return it as a stdClass

Comment: Life saver.  Thanks!

Comment: This is ok, but the values come back quoted.  How to get rid of them?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in PHP 5.5 - decided to update to PHP 5.6, but the problem still existed. Casting to CHAR helps, but it isn't good solution.

My PHP configuration was using libmysqlclient and when I changed it to mysqlnd (MySQL native driver) it solved the problem.

So I recommend to do the same.

You can read about PHP MySQL drivers here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php

I installed mysqlnd driver in Ubuntu server using apt-get:

apt-get install php5-mysqlnd

Answer (score 1):

As a small addendum.  Casting the column to a char like that has the effect of returning the value with double quotes around it.  You can get rid of them using trim:

```
select *, TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM CAST(json_col as CHAR)) as json_col from table_with_json_type
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use laravel or lumen, at this to config/database.php

```
'options' => [PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true]
```

else may be try to install myslnd

```
apt-get install php7.0-mysqlnd
```

Ref this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/json-column-problem-with-mysql57-and-laravel52#reply-191316