# when retrieving json data from the json column type in mysql 5.7 using laravel 5.2 getting error

Tags: json, laravel-5, php-5.6, mysql-5.7

Iam usin mysql 5.7,laravel5.2 and php 5.6.17 in my application..

I created a migration table

```
   public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admin_login_history', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->json('client_details');
            $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I created a model for it..

```
class AdminLoginHistory extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'admin_login_history';

    protected $fillable = ['file_path', 'url', 'user_id', 'client_details'];

    protected $casts = ['client_details' => 'json'];
}
```

Iam inserting a array of data of client_details which is converted to json  in  my model.

now when retrieving the data from the table iam getting error

```
$loginhistory = AdminLoginHistory::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

Error:

```
File Path: /home/storage/elivio/InvizoAdmin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php
Error Code:HY000,  Line Number:669
Message:SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2036 (SQL: select * from `admin_login_history` where `user_id` = 1 order by `created_at` desc limit 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253778/php-pdo-query-error-on-table-has-json-data-type-mysql-5-7-8-rc). JSON data is still relative new in MySQL so I imagine it'll take a little while before things are rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

"As of MySQL 5.7.8, MySQL supports a native JSON data type... " So check if you have the correct versión of mysql (5.7.8 or newer).

[Mysql 5.7.8 JSON data type, doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)