# Laravel 5.2 query building for JSON on columns

Tags: php, mysql, orm, laravel-5

I am using MySql 5.7.14 and laravel 5.2.
My Table 'user' JSON look like this:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "options": "{\"religion\": \"R'hllor, the Lord of Light\", \"favorite_color\": \"red\"}"
}]
```

when i query through the laravel as:

```
$ii =\DB::table('user')->where('options->favorite_color', 'red')->get();
```

i am facing error as

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2036 (SQL: select * from `user` where `options`->"$.favorite_color" = red)
```

and when i run the same query as

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE options->"$.favorite_color"='red'
```

in phpmyadmin its not giving any error it working fine.
Can anyone tell me what may be the issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253778/php-pdo-query-error-on-table-has-json-data-type-mysql-5-7-8-rc

Comment: can you show that how data stored in your Table, specially options column ?

Comment: thanks Mike. I will go through that link.

Comment: @Qazi : Options column look like: {"religion": "R'hllor, the Lord of Light", "favorite_color": "red"}

Answer (score 10):

I got the solution.
To work with MySQL 5.7.8 and above using laravel 5.2 need to add the PDO options to the your connections in config/database.php as follows.

```
 'mysql' => [
  'driver'    => 'mysql',
  'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
  'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db_name'),
  'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
  'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
  'charset'   => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
  'prefix'    => '',
  'strict'    => false,
   'options'   => array(
           PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_LOWER,
           PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
           PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_NATURAL,
           PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => true,
           PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true,
       ),

],
```

and then run php artisan config:cache.
Its works well.
vendor/laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php PDO Options are like

```
protected $options = [
    PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS => PDO::NULL_NATURAL,
    PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
];
```

PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES & PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES Need To Be Overwritten in database.php.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me!

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: Dude! You freak'n kick ass :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

check Your Php Version and if its not 7.0 or 7.1

Then Point it to Correct Version

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
```

Worked For Me